# How to edit spacing of TreeView nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

In my program I have a `TreeView` as a view element that displays nodes as strings. I would like to add more space between each node (basically make it so that it is not so condensed). Is there a way to do this through xaml? I have looked through all of the properties in the [`TreeView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) and have not had any luck finding a corresponding property. If I cannot do this is xaml, how would I go about it in C#?

This is my `TreeView` style implementation:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
             <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasCommands}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewEmptyMenu}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasCommands}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemContextMenu}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update: Right click options using @Chris W.'s answer**

[image]

Comment: Depending on whether you want the extra spacing to be inside or outside the selection border, you can look into setting a custom `ItemTemplate` or `ItemContainerStyle` (with `Template`), respectively.

Comment: @MikeStrobel glad I'm not the only one with the habit of putting answers as comments and foregoing the point gluttony :) but I'd throw that on there too, my answer was more towards making it a global thing to forget it, yours would definitely be better for the instance with just a quick specified ItemTemplate. Cheers

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot for the help so far. I think I would rather opt for just making the change on this specific instance of the `treeView`, because I would not want to affect the other `treeViews` in my program. The solution with the `ItemTemplate` sounds nice because then I can probably just make the change in the tree's xaml. With that being said, I do not actually know the code it would take to tell the `treeView` how to space it's lines differently. Would either of you guys be able to share an example?

Answer (score 0):

So if we go take a look at the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048(v=vs.110).aspx) we see in there a `ContentPresenter` and an `ItemsPresenter` you could either go and just set a hard value Margin on like `Margin="0,5"` or whatever space you need. Or bind it to the template so you could enter the value inline at the instance.

You can get to this with just a quick Right-Click on your `TreeView` in your Document Outline or on the design editor and choose Edit Template->Edit Current or Edit a copy, or you should be able to hit the item template by choosing Edit Additional Templates->Edit Item, if you do Edit current, you'll edit the base default template, if you choose to make a copy then it will assign that style template explicitly to the instance. XAML only should be required here, no code otherwise, and it's easy peazy.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: In the second half of your answer you talk about assigning a style template explicitly to the instance of `treeView` that I am working on. That would be perfect for me! The only problem is that when I double click on the `treeView` in my design editor I do not see an "Edit Template" option like you talk about. I will add a screen shot of the drop down menu that I get instead in my question.

Comment: Right-click, not double-click, it should be right there on the context menu that pops up if you're using VS2012+ but if you're using like VS2010 then you'd use Expression Blend to do the same. From your picture maybe you're using VS2010?

Comment: Correct, I am in VS2010.

Comment: What would I do if I don't have Expression Blend? Probably just a xaml solution?

Comment: Expression blend just makes it easier, but the default style template would be in one of your resource dictionaries, I forget what the default resource dictionary names are in WPF, maybe just do a quick solution search for "TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" would find it for you, then you'd have the template to edit at the source or could copy and use it at the instance level instead of global.